# WP the_content display plugins attachments only

Tags: wordpress

This might be a silly question since I'm new to wp but i'm trying to create a custom post feed.

Basically i have this loop

```
while ( have_posts() ){
   the_post();
   the_title();
   the_post_thumbnail('content-thumb');

   //and here i have installed facebook share plugin
   //so if i put the_content() it would display share button
   //the problem is it also display post text and everything else while i only 
   //need that plugin button or whatever comes with that plugin

}
```

Comment: Which plugin do you use?

Comment: @Vidhi http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons/

Comment: try `echo do_shortcode('really_simple_share button="facebook_like"');` inside loop to put facebook share button

Comment: @Vidhi I dont want to use shortcodes because then i cant use any of the settings in admin panel, i guess you could say i want to use the_content() function without any content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook share plugin is most probably hooking the button code to `the_content` filter hook. The only way to avoid both 'the content' and the 'facebook button' from both displaying at once is to unhook the button from `the_content` using `remove_filter()` and then add the button manually to the page.

Read more about WordPress hooks in the [Plugin API/Hooks article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks).

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Comment: Awesome thats what i was looking for, i was able to to unhook `really_simple_share_content` from the content, now i only need to find a way to add it where it needs to be

Comment: okay nevermind apperently i only needed to call that function, wp is so confusing for me after coming from OOP based frameworks... thanks a lot for your help!